# How to marshal a java List with out XML root element using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have huge list of java Objects, want to marshal that list without a root element, using JAXB. Is it possible to do ?.

I have a list something like this

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>

Expected Output:
<element>
  ----------
  ---------
</element>
<element>
  ---------
  ---------
<element>
```

How can I marshal in such a way,

Any reference or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the list marshalling each item individually.  You will need to set the `JAXB_FRAGMENT` property on the `Marshaller` to prevent the XML header from being written out.  You will only need to create the `JAXBContext` and `Marshaller` once for this use case.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Element.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(new Element());
        elements.add(new Element());

        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/forum18509018/out.txt")) {
           for(Element element : elements) {
               marshaller.marshal(element, fos);
           }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for you response, I don't want to do that , Iterating through list and marshaling them to file takes lot of time especially when you processing with huge data.That's why i want to process the list once.Is there better way to do it ?

Comment: @user964147 - If you create the `JAXBContext` and `Marshaller` once why do you anticipate there will be a performance difference between marshalling a list with N items and marshalling N items individually?

Comment: I am experiencing it, If you marshal single entry and writing them to file and again marshaling other entry appending to the file, which obviously takes more time than appending bunch of data to file.

Comment: @user964147 - Are you marshalling to a single instance of `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: @ Blaise Doughan- Yes I am marshaling to only single instance of File

Comment: @user964147 - Have you tried marshalling to a single instance of `FileOutputStream` instead of `File`?